# scrapr image url from wikipedia page

Tags: php, regex

I created regex which gives image url from the source code of the page.

```
<?php
function get_logo($html, $url)
{
//preg_match_all('', $html, $matches);
//preg_match_all('~\b((\w+ps?://)?\S+(png|jpg))\b~im', $html, $matches);
    if (preg_match_all('/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpg)\b/', $html, $matches)) {
        echo "First";
        return $matches[0][0];
    } else {
        if (preg_match_all('~\b((\w+ps?://)?\S+(png|jpg))\b~im', $html, $matches)) {
            echo "Second";
            return url_to_absolute($url, $matches[0][0]);
//return $matches[0][0];
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```

But for wikipedia page image url is like this

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nelson_Mandela-2008_(edit).jpg`
which always fails in my regex.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: [Don't use a regular expression to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)! Instead use XPath, which would yield your result with ease.

Comment: You should ***not*** use regular expressions to parse HTML or XML. Instead, you should use a tool like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that provides the proper capability to parse these types of files.

Comment: +1 for each of the suggestions above.  DOM parsing is often easier to implement, read, understand and maintain.  Also, as with any website content scraping, be sure to check the target website's terms of use to ensure you're not violating them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why try to parse HTML with regex when this can easily be done with the `DOMDocument` class in PHP.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLfile( "http://www.wikipedia.org/" );

$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img");

foreach( $images as $image ) {
    echo $image->getAttribute("src");
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$image->getAttribute('src')` instead of using a foreach loop for all attributes?

Comment: @AeroX: Can you please modify it to get only one imag url?

Comment: @Programming_crazy: The above code give you the content of the src attribute inside img tags. It is only an example for the first step of the code, it is not the gift-wrapped solution.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for the tip on `$image->getAttribute('src')`. Edited answer to use that method.