# Make all img tags' src attributes contain absolute paths

Tags: php, replace, html-parsing, domdocument, src

I am trying to get/replace the image source link from the page.

Some of the page has image `src='image/abc.png'` so my regex fails.

What I want to do is: append the subdirectory path to main url if absolute path is not given.
i.e. if `src='image/abc.png` and main url is `http://example.com`

then it should transformed to `http://example.com/image/abc.png`

Note: some user may enter the url name like `http://example.com/` so if I append as I did above then it will give:

`http://example.com//image/abc.png` which is wrong.

Can someone give me correct directions to form the exact absolute path of image?

My code:

```
<?php
function get_logo($html, $url) {
    if (preg_match_all('/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpg)\b/', $html, $matches)) {
        echo "First:";
        return $matches[0][0];
    } else {
        if (preg_match_all('~\b((\w+ps?://)?\S+(png|jpg))b~im', $html, $matches)) {
            echo "Second:  ";
            echo $matches[0][0];
            return url_to_absolute($url, $matches[0][0]);
//return $matches[0][0];
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` instead of regexes, then just check for each `img` if its `src` attribute starts with HTTP or not.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568294/scrap-image-url-from-wikipedia-page

Comment: @AeroX: Please read the question again. `DOM` i could not use and here I am trying to get solution in different way.

Comment: @AeroX: is this correct? `if( $image->attributes->name == "src")
 echo $image->attributes->value;`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't use regex for this task.  Using a combination of DOMDocument and XPath will make quick work of this task and the syntax is rather intuitive.  If the `src` attribute of any `<img>` tag does not `start with` your pre-declared domain, then trim any forward slashes from the front of the `src` value and prepend the domain to form the absolute path.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/subbr))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
   <img src="image/abc.png" alt="test" width="50" height="50">
   <img src="http://example.com/image/abc.png" alt="test" width="50" height="50">
   <img src="/image/abc.png" alt="test" width="50" height="50">
   <iframe src="image/abc.png" alt="test" width="50" height="50"></iframe>
</div>
HTML;

$base = "http://example.com/";

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//img[not(starts-with(@src, '$base'))]") as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('src', $base . ltrim($node->getAttribute('src'), '/'));
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
   <img src="http://example.com/image/abc.png" alt="test" width="50" height="50">
   <img src="http://example.com/image/abc.png" alt="test" width="50" height="50">
   <img src="http://example.com/image/abc.png" alt="test" width="50" height="50">
   <iframe src="image/abc.png" alt="test" width="50" height="50"></iframe>
</div>
```